# OptaPlanner: How can I build a solver without .xml config file?

Tags: java, optaplanner

As default, I'm a beginner about OptaPlanner and I find all solvers are built by the xml configuration file in OptaPlanner. So I want to know how can I build my solver just using pure java code, just like

```
SolverFactory.setScoreCalculator(new NQueensEasyScoreCalculator()).setSearch(new ***()).build();
```

In other word, we don't need other xml file and can use the above solver to solve the problem.
So anyone can tell me how can I deal it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: With the optaplanner-spring-boot-starter that will be released in 7.32.0.Final, the XML is optional, it just figures it out automatically.

Comment: Wa~ Look forward it，thx Geo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can build the configuration using the `SolverConfig` fluent API. For example:

```java
SolverConfig solverConfig = new SolverConfig()
        .withEnvironmentMode(EnvironmentMode.REPRODUCIBLE)
        .withSolutionClass(VehicleRoutingSolution.class)
        .withEntityClasses(Standstill.class, PlanningVisit.class)
        .withScoreDirectorFactory(new ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig().withScoreDrls("org/optaweb/vehiclerouting/solver/vehicleRoutingScoreRules.drl"))
        .withTerminationConfig(new TerminationConfig().withSecondsSpentLimit(60L))
        .withPhases(
                new ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig().withConstructionHeuristicType(ConstructionHeuristicType.FIRST_FIT_DECREASING),
                new LocalSearchPhaseConfig().withLocalSearchType(LocalSearchType.TABU_SEARCH)
        );
```

Then you can use the config to build a solver with `SolverFactory`:

```java
SolverFactory<VehicleRoutingSolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(solverConfig);
Solver<VehicleRoutingSolution> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
```

In your case the configuration might be simpler. I included more options to illustrate the possibilities.